# windows shortcut to device properties

Tags: windows, shortcuts

[image: default audio device properties, advanced tab]

Is there any way to create a shortcut that will open the default (or even a specific) audio device properties with the 'advanced' tab already selected?

**edit** - going off of @heavyd's answer, I made a batch file with the following contents:

```
start "Sound" "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,playback
```

then pinned it to my start menu - which at the very least gets me straight to the playback device properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular dialog is a modal dialog that is opened from the Sound settings page.  I think the best you're going to get with just a shortcut is to get the Sound settings window to open.  You can use this to open the playback devcies:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,playback
```

You could probably get where you want with AutoHotKey or similar tool.

Comment: oh yeah, that's a step in the right direction - and I'll look into autohotkey.